# How to use Location objects in tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, location

I'm trying to write tests to test some code manipulating [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location) objects.
Using the `@Before` JUnit annotation, I want to initialize a Location instance, this way:

```java
@Before
fun init_service() {
    location = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
    System.out.println("init $location")
}
```

When executing my tests, the output isn't very satisfying, printing: `init null`.

Knowing that this piece of code works in a classical context, is there a special way to init object instances in a test context?

Comment: Can you share your complete test class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test Android specific code you need to shadow SDK classes. You can use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/). Just add dependency to `build.gradle` and annotate your test class with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`

```
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationManager
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class Test {

    @Before
    fun init_service() {
        val location = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        location.latitude = 22.234
        location.longitude = 23.394
        println(location)
    }
}
```